# How to dynamically scale a service in Openshift ? A Challenging scenario

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, autoscaling

I'm currently trying to deploy a backend service API for my application in Openshift, which needs to be scalable such that each of the request has to run in a new pod.

Service will take 5 minutes to serve single request.
I have to hit the service for 700 times.

Is there a way I can create 700 pods to serve the 700 request and scaled down it to 1 after all the requests are completed ?

Start of the application:
1 pod <- 700 requests

Serving:
700 pod serves one request each

End of the application:
1 pod

Comment: Any reason why you need 1 request per pod? why not 7 pods that will serve concurrently 100 requests/threads?

Comment: Our service will take 5-10 minutes to serve one request. So we are planning to run each request in a new pod to save the total processing time.

Answer (score 1):

Autoscaling in Kubernetes relies on metrics. From what I know Openshift supports [CPU and Memory utilization](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/pod_autoscaling.html#hpa-supported-metrics).

But I don't think this is what you are looking for.

I think you should be looking into [Jobs - Run to Completion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/).

Each request will spawn a new `Job` which will run until it's completed.

Example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

This will run a job which computes π to 2000 places and prints it out.